# How to use save model for prediction in python

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nltk, prediction

I am doing a text classification in python and I want to use it in production environment for making prediction on new document. I am using TfidfVectorizer to build bagofWord.

I am doing:

```
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_documents_for_train, classLabel).toarray()
```

Then I am doing cross validation and building the model using SVM. After that I am saving the model.

For making prediction on my test data I am loading that model in **another script** where I have the same TfidfVectorizer and I know I can't do fit_transform on my testing data. I have to do:

```
X_test = vectorizer.transform(clean_test_documents, classLabel).toarray()
```

But this is not possible because I have to fit first. I know there is a way. I can load my training data and perform `fit_transform` like I did during building the model but my training data is very large and every time I want to predict I can't do that. So my question is:

- Is there a way I can use TfidfVectorizer on my test data and perform prediction ?
- Is there any other way to perform prediction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vectorizer is part of your model. When you save your trained SVM model, you need to also save the corresponding vectorizer.

To make this more convenient, you can use [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to construct a single "fittable" object that represents the steps needed to transform raw input to prediction output. In this case, the pipeline consists of a Tf-Idf extractor and an SVM classifier:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
clf = svm.SVC()
tfidf_svm = Pipeline([('tfidf', vectorizer), ('svc', clf)])

documents, y = load_training_data()
tfidf_svm.fit(documents, y)
```

This way, only a single object needs to be persisted:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(tfidf_svm, 'model.pkl')
```

To apply the model on your testing document, load the trained pipeline and simply use its `predict` function as usual with raw document(s) as input.

Answer (score 3):

I was redirected here based on the search "How to use saved model for prediction?". So just to add to YS-L's answer, the final step.

Saving the model

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(fittedModel, 'name.model')
```

Load the saved model and predict

```
fittedModel = joblib.load('name.model')
fittedModel.predict(X_new)  # X_new is unseen example to be predicted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the clf.predict with the .apply and lambda

```
datad['Predictions']=datad['InputX'].apply(lambda x: unicode(clf.predict(count_vect.transform([x]))))
```